# Rails - How to set number collection to DESC in select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Have a number range as collection in simple form select field.

```
<%= f.input :college_class, as: :select, collection: 1940..2018, 
    prompt: '----', hint: 'Year', :input_html => { :class => 'span1'} %>
```

How can I set the number range so it's in DESC order in the select field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [downto](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-downto) method, like so:

```
<%= f.input :college_class, as: :select, collection: 2018.downto(1940), 
prompt: '----', hint: 'Year', :input_html => { :class => 'span1'} %>
```